# Does $F(x)=\int ^{2x-x^2}_0 cos(\frac{1}{1+t^2})dt$ have a maximum or a minimum value?

Tags: calculus

Does the function

$F(x)=\int ^{2x-x^2}_0 cos(\frac{1}{1+t^2})dt$ have a maximum or a minimum value?

Attempt:

By Fundamental theorem of calculus, we have

$F'(x)=cos(\frac{1}{1+(2x-x^2)^2})(2-2x)$

$F'(x)=0$ when $x=1$ and for a root  that makes $cos(.)=0$

depending on this root. We have a max or a min.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The term $\cos\left(\frac{1}{1+(2x-x^2)}\right)$ is always positive, since $0\lt \frac{1}{1+(2x-x^2)^2}\le 1$.

It follows that $F'(x)\gt 0$ for $x\lt 1$, and $F'(x)\lt 0$ for $x\gt 1$. Thus $F$ is increasing until $x=1$, and then decreasing, and therefore $F(x)$ reaches an absolute maximum at $x=1$. There is no absolute (or local) minimum.